# Make a Bit Continent

Tags: code-golf, binary-matrix

Let's imagine we have a matrix of bits (which contains at least one `1`):

```
0 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 0
0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 0
0 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 0
1 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 1
0 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 0
```

We want to set some of the bits in this matrix such that it forms a contiguous blob of `1`s, in which every `1` is directly or indirectly connected to every other `1` through orthogonal movement:

```
0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 0
0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 0
0 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 0
1 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 1
0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 0
```

(You can see this more clearly by searching for `1` with your browser's "find" feature.)

However, we also want to minimize the number of bits that we set.

### The Task

Given a matrix (or array of arrays) of bits or booleans, return the minimum number of bits that need to be set to create a contiguous continent of `1`s. It should be possible to get from one set bit in the matrix to another by only traveling in an orthogonal direction to other set bits.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest valid submission (measured in bytes) wins.

### Test Cases

```
0 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 0
0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 0
0 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 0
1 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 1
0 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 0
=> 6

1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0
1 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 0
1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1
0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1
0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0
1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0
=> 4

0 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 1
0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0
0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0
1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 0
0 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 1
0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0
1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 0
1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1
0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1
1 1 0 0 1 1 0 1 1
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0
0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 1
0 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 0
0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1
=> 8

1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1
=> 0
```

Comment: This needs a bit more explaining. What is a "contiguous blob" in a matrix?

Comment: What are the parameters in which we express the complexity?

Comment: @xnor What do you mean by this?

Comment: @Challenger5 Never mind, I see you added "(in the number of bits in the matrix)" regarding the time complexity.

Comment: Since the problem is [known to be NP-hard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rectilinear_Steiner_tree) it's not a good problem for [tag:fastest-algorithm].

Comment: Is it just me or is this the TSP in disguise

Comment: @PeterTaylor This challenge just asks to find how many bits *need* to be set, not what bits *to* set. Would that make a difference?

Comment: Unlikely in the general case, and [no in this case](http://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/0132071).

Comment: @Peter Taylor and esolangingfruit [NP-Hardness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-hardness)

Comment: In light of Peter Taylor and HyperNeutrino's comments, and the fact that the question currently has no answers, I'm changing the scoring method to [tag:code-golf].

Comment: What should we do if there's no `1` in the matrix?

Comment: @ColeraSu You don't have to handle that case.

Answer (score 2):

## C (gcc), <s>308</s> 306 bytes

Function `f` receives `(height, width, flattened array, pointer to ans)`, and returns answer by pointer.

If there's no `1` in the matrix, it will return `0`.

```c
#define v A[i]
N,M,K,R,C,T,i,*A;s(x,y){i=x*M+y;if(!(x<0|y<0|x>=N|y>=M|v^1))v=2,s(x,y+1),s(x,y-1),s(x+1,y),s(x-1,y);}g(i){if(C<R){if(i^K){g(i+1);if(!v)C+=v=1,g(i+1),v=0,C--;}else{T=1;for(i=0;i<K&&!v;i++);s(i/M,i%M);for(i=0;i<K;i++)T&=v^1,v=!!v;if(T)R=C;}}}f(n,m,a,b)int*a,*b;{K=R=(N=n)*(M=m),A=a;g(0);*b=R;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lVHBioMwEL37FWmXSqIjaxZ6SqdQPIo9iLfSgm1NCWzdpV2CYvPt7qi7UPa2YZK8mTfz8iCn6HI69f3LudKmrphlm53Ze1vIIIUcEijAQLBRd95AKzqDTZCFrTKaz3izih8t7WaN20e7xuxhD1IIi28wtodSTCCaQChJYgDRAJS7cEOKmierfLzNIRUdFWlufMCKJESLEqYaWIwhiSLlqvd71RUolf64cYOxMqvU92dWmTAUZNW8ZmAWmXjmR67wkSyS0Gxo1rwQOSbKOad5DVco4ShM/RWUEBxVl2KOfIu1CHiGVwEbLNWFx0IFR8yV66mTXUtTc@F1HhuyZLdnyLoYGIX8OT32tCbqN/5S8v9T8omSTk0@yvpOSPMlLOkHfUoF5Z834jSfL85zmEqu/wY)

**Ungolfed:**

```c
N,M,R,C,T,i,*A; // height, width, result, recursion depth

s(x,y)
{ // depth first search: replace all 1 in the same connected component with 2
    i=x*M+y;
    if(!(x<0|y<0|x>=N|y>=M|A[i]^1)) { // check if out of boundary
        A[i]=2;
        s(x, y+1),s(x, y-1),s(x+1, y),s(x-1, y);
    }
}

g(i)
{ // enumerate all posible solutions
    if(C<R) {
        if(i!=N*M) {
            g(i+1);      // nothing change for this entry
            if (!A[i]) { // set the entry to 1
                C++, A[i]=1;
                g(i+1);
                C--, A[i]=0;
            }
        }
        else {
            T=1;
            for (i=0; i<N*M && !A[i]; i++); // find first non-zero entry
            s(i/M, i%M);     // replace the connected component
            for (i=0; i<N*M; i++) {
                T&=A[i]!=1;   // check if no other components
                A[i]=!!A[i]; // change 2s back to 1
            }
            if (T) R=C;      // update answer
        }
    }
}

f(n,m,a,b)int*a,*b;{
    R=(N=n)*(M=m), A=a;
    g(0);
    *b=R;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 611 bytes

A full program that takes a list of lists through user input. The functions `I` and `d` count the number of islands in the array. The for loop at the end enumerates through all possibilities of where you can change `0`s to `1`s then if there is one island left stores the number of `1`s added to the list `C`. The minimum of that list is the minimum number of bit flips required to connect any islands. It is a very slow algorithm so it doesn't run the test cases given in under 60s (I didn't try longer) but I tried a few smaller (~5x5) test cases and it seems to be working correctly. I got the island counting algorithm from [this](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-number-of-islands/) page.

```python
from itertools import*
def d(g,i,j,v):
 v[i][j],R,C=1,[-1,1,0,0],[0,0,-1,1]
 for k in range(4):
	if len(g)>i+R[k]>=0<=j+C[k]<len(g[0]):
	 if v[i+R[k]][j+C[k]]<1and g[i+R[k]][j+C[k]]:v=d(g,i+R[k],j+C[k],v)
 return v
def I(g):
 w=len(g[0])
 v,c=[w*[0]for r in g],0
 for i in range(len(g)*w):
	if v[i/w][i%w]<1and g[i/w][i%w]>0:v=d(g,i/w,i%w,v);c+=1
 return c           
g=input()
C=[]
for p in [list(t)for t in product([0,1],repeat=sum(r.count(0)for r in g))]:
 h,G,x=0,[r[:]for r in g],len(g[0])
 for i in range(x*len(G)):
	if G[i/x][i%x]<1:h+=p[0];G[i/x][i%x]=p[0];del p[0]
 if I(G)<2:
	C.append(h)
print min(C)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XZI/k8IgEMXr41PQ3AzoniY3V6nYpHBsbRkKJ8GIJoRBYrxP7y2J/84UDDx25/0eWfcb9o39vl53vqmpCdqHpqlO1NSu8WFECr2jBSvBwAHOfEboWRolDwo2kIkU5FcKKSSQKJC4QjwqQneNp0dqLPVbW2r2g40fZkcrbVnJl2a8kUe1FMlCHMYZbhf9hUxUrKNYiCZ9DTr1BWqRbm1By3d5dhY9XK/CICImoV6H1lt67vnXaIrknXjYYAzIhexGeIisPrKWCpIB3TzRB@RRd0uAYNNOSfPZPZHuwjK540w7QAFB5vlYpA@anD4/UgpjXRsYJ5mQikRbF21lZU6BBR6FEAXnm6LNA8P3TRV47fQ2iFNbMz/Jm9YGlvBnBM4VJt3DCi4iAenl7F@@lwd4y3kZxbsVv@VcYaxLjHXBnLP9WDjsmr@og1DoisYNiT9tje2Lb@zPJlvntC3YnhPnjQ20NpZl/HqVMg5L@hiXYXD6AcJw6g8)

Pregolfed version before I optimized a few things:

```py
from itertools import*
def d(g,i,j,v):
    v[i][j]=1
    R=[-1,1,0,0]
    C=[0,0,-1,1]
    for k in range(4):
        if len(g)>i+R[k]>=0<=j+C[k]<len(g[0]):
            if v[i+R[k]][j+C[k]]<1:
                if g[i+R[k]][j+C[k]]:
                    v=d(g,i+R[k],j+C[k],v)
    return v
def I(g):
    w=len(g[0])
    v=[[0]*w for r in g]
    c=0
    for i in range(len(g)):
        for j in range(w):
            if v[i][j]<1and g[i][j]>0:
                v=d(g,i,j,v)
                c+=1
    return c           
g=input()
z=sum(r.count(0)for r in g)
f=[list(t)for t in product('01',repeat=z)]
C=[]
for p in f:
    h=0
    G=[r[:]for r in g]
    x=len(G[0])
    for i in range(x*len(G)):
        exec('h+=int(p[0]);G[i/x][i%x]=int(p[0]);del p[0]'*(G[i/x][i%x]<1))
    if I(G)<2:
        C.append(h)
print min(C)
```